# Objective C: How to implement MapKit Method - (NSSet *)annotationsInMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit

I am trying to implement the method below to select the set of annotations in the visible region of my map.

```
- (NSSet *)annotationsInMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
```

I added the line in my code as such

```
NSSet *nearbySet = [self annotationsInMapRect:self.mapView.frame];
```

My app is crashing because of this. Can anyone advise on how I should use the above method correctly?

EDIT:
Stack Trace is as follows:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CarParkTableViewController annotationsInMapRect:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x187b60'
```

Thanks

Zhen Hoe

Comment: What error is on the console? And please provide the stacktrace.

Comment: @Nick, I have added the stack trace to the original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
NSSet *nearbySet = [self.mapView annotationsInMapRect:self.mapView.frame];
```

Your posted error shows that self is not an instance of MKMapView but annotationsInMapRect is a message you can send only to that class.

Comment: /Users/zhenhoeyong/Documents/Developer/CarParkFinder/Classes/CarParkTableViewController.m:93:0 /Users/zhenhoeyong/Documents/Developer/CarParkFinder/Classes/CarParkTableViewController.m:93: @Nick, I am getting the following error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'annotationsInMapRect:'. Any advise how I can resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to pass something simple like: CGRectMake(0,0,100,100); ?

Comment: I used the following: nearbyCarSet = [self.mapView annotationsInMapRect:self.mapView.visibleMapRect]; and it works now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this answer... The method should only accept MKMapRect that is totally different from the RECT of the view.

i would use

```
NSSet *nearbySet = [self.mapView annotationsInMapRect:self.mapView.visibleMapRect];
```